# count number of value per id in array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this script in php i want to get the number of value in the table
in below my script

```
$count = 0;
         
foreach ($info as $key => $value)
{
    foreach ($value as $c => $val)
    {
        var_dump($val) . "<br>";
                 
        if (strcmp($val,"Tankh ") == 0)
        {
            $count++;
            //echo $count;
        }
    }

    // die();
                      
    echo $count;
    return $count;
```

var_dump the `$val`:

```
string(9) "Nomclient" 
string(13) "Villeclient " 
string(7) "Mohamed" 
string(8) "Tankh " 
string(6) "Fatima" 
string(9) "Tankh " 
string(6) "Brahim" 
string(6) "Tankh " 
string(5) "Jamal" 
string(8) "Tankh " 
string(5) "Ikram" 
string(6) "Tankh " 
string(6) "Karima" 
string(5) "Rain"
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "the number of value per id"? What "id"? Please give us more details and an example of what exactly you're expecting to get from the current output.

Comment: After implementing @Dèjà vu solution return the $count out of 1st for each loop rather than 2nd for each you're doing now

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want something like this... if I understand correctly:

```
$val_counts = array();

foreach ($info as $key => $value)
{
   foreach ($value as $c => $val)
   {
      $val_counts[$val]++;
   }
}
```

Then later, var_dump($val_counts) and you'll see how many time each value was in your 2-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can leverage the existing function [array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) for every `$value` instead of checking the individual values.

```
$info = [
    [
        "Nomclient", "Villeclient", "Mohamed", "Tankh", "Fatima", "Tankh", "Brahim", "Tankh", "Jamal", "Tankh", "Ikram", "Tankh", "Karima", "Rain"
    ]
];

$val_counts = array_map(function($value){
    return array_count_values($value);
}, $info);

print_r($val_counts);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Nomclient] => 1
            [Villeclient] => 1
            [Mohamed] => 1
            [Tankh] => 5
            [Fatima] => 1
            [Brahim] => 1
            [Jamal] => 1
            [Ikram] => 1
            [Karima] => 1
            [Rain] => 1
        )

)
```

[PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/lU6J0)